# How to apply active class for first list item using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div class="accordion">
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Demo</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can we apply a class which is 'active' to first 'li' (ie;Lorem) only, not for all first 'li' under 'ul' using jquery.
I would like to get output as

```
<div class="accordion">
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active">Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Demo</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) (as opposed to [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) which would get the first per-`<ul>`), and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) like this:

```
$(".accordion li:first").addClass("active");
```

Or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/), which is an alias for [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`.slice(0,1)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) even, like this:

```
$(".accordion li").first().addClass("active");
//or
$(".accordion li").eq(0).addClass("active");
//or
$(".accordion li:eq(0)").addClass("active");
//or
$(".accordion li").slice(0,1).addClass("active");
```

There are a few ways to go about it...though I prefer [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) for clarity.