# JQuery - setting an "active" class for image-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have content loading dynamically (using new WP_query loop in WordPress) for a jQuery carousel or image-scroll function -- where the image-scroll is a li list of images, styled to look like a strip of images.

When the image-scroll works properly, one of the images in the li tag has a class of active, which expands the image and makes it look like it's in front of the other images,

... and as the user clicks through this strip of images, the active class changes/moves to the targeted li tag, expanding that image.

What's happening is that none of the li tags are active when the page loads - since the content is dynamic through the WP loop (I didn't want all of the li tags to start with the active class, so I didn't add it to the loop),

...and so the images are just lined up in a consistent strip w/o one of the images being expanded (or having that active class).

It is only if the user happens to click on one of the images that it expands,

**...but i need one of the images to be expanded (to have the class of active) before the user clicks so I need the active class added as/after the page loads.**

I have tried through the jQuery code to target one of the li tags to add the active class, using `filter()` or `closest()` after the page loads, but that didn't work.

Or maybe I should write a new script to add the active class?

Any help much appreciated!

I have the abbreviated html and the jQuery function below.

_Cindy

ps as the code indicates, I also have corresponding article titles that scroll with the images, so perhaps I need to adjust the jQuery there, too.

```
    <div class="articles-scroll">

<ul class="images-scroll">
    <li><!-- I need only one of these tags to have a class of active to start -->

        <a href="#">
            <span class="set-image-border" style="float: none;">
               <img class="setborder" src="image-set-by-new-wp_query">
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="set-image-border">
               <img class="setborder" src="image-set-by-new-wp_query">
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="clear-float"></div>

<!-- in this section of html one of the article titles is active to coordinate with the active li image above to produce a corresponding clickable title, this works, but once again, only when user clicks on an image to begin the jQuery image-scroll function -->

        <div class="wrapper">

<ul class="images-content">
    <li>
            <div class="article-header">
                <h2>
                    <a href="link-set-by-new-wp_query">
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="article-header">
                <h2>
                    <a href="link-set-by-new-wp_query">
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>


    jQuery(".images-scroll li a").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("li").removeClass("active");
// tried the following instruction as well as on next line, but no go
// jQuery(this).parent().parent().closest("li").addClass("active");
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".images-content > li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".images-content > li").eq(jQuery(this).parent().index()).addClass("active");
    var step = ((-250)*(jQuery(this).parent().index()-1))-60;
    //alert(step);
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().css("margin-left", step+"px");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: Hi thank you so much. I need the active class to be added to one of the <li> tags as indicated above -  the jQuery function adds the active class only if a user happens to click on the <li> tag which holds an image. re: <!-- [the function] adds [the active ] class [] only when user clicks [on the link within the li tag which holds an image, but one of the li tags should be set to active at the start [or to say after the page loads]-->

Comment: ... so one of the li tags for ul class="images-scroll needs to have the active class added after the page loads (which is an image of an article) -- and the corresponding li tag for ul class="images-content also needs to be active (which is the title of the article); the jQuery function only works if a user happens to click on one of the images in the scroll function (ul.class="images-scroll" > li).

Comment: I ish *confused*. In short you want the `<li>` tag to add a class of active if they clicked it?

Comment: I want the <li> tag to have the active class before the user clicks on one of the <li> tags - so add it after the page loads... I guess maybe that answers my question set up a separate script altogether? The information with the <li> tags loads dynamically (through WP_query) so that's why the active class isn't added to begin with to one of the <li> tags.

Comment: Made edits to my question and tried to be a little more clear with the help I needed. I am learning javascript/jQuery, but it seems once I'm out in the "real world" developing web pages, I'm still not pulling together the whole picture. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the code you wrote didn't work is that you have it inside a click handler, so nothing happens until you click one of the targeted elements. If you want something to happen on page load you can use `$(document).ready()` (can be shortened as `$()`) or `$(window).load()`. Just add the following lines below or above your existing code.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $listItems = jQuery('.images-scroll li');
    $listItems.first().addClass('active');
    // Second list item
    $listItems.eq(1).addClass('active');
    // Third list item
    $listItems.eq(2).addClass('active');
});
```

Also, please note that (unless it conflicts with a different plugin), writing `$` is shorter than `jQuery`, and it should do the same.

Comment: DJDavid98 thanks for the help and hanging in there w me. Yes that worked -- with one small change, adding the period before class name. (something so simple, understanding the click function).

Comment: also went on to add "... ('.images-scroll li:nth-child(2)') ..." and " ... ('.images-scroll li:nth-child(2)') ..." to target the 2nd li tag, although likely a better way, maybe with .eq(1) -- taking a hint from a stackoverflow answer in 2010 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077339/how-to-apply-active-class-for-first-list-item-using-jquery

Comment: @ccbar Updated answer. If you feel it has helped solving your problem, please click the check mark below the vote buttons to mark it as accepted.